# Scrape QTY from web-page, but can't find with inspect element

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape a [web page](https://www.giordano.co.kr/shop/detail.php?pno=F30DACCEC8DAEDA7E4ADBA492C474276) but I couldn't find the wanted element for **available *qty*** using browser's action [*Inspect Element*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Select_and_highlight_elements#with_the_html_pane).

#### How I got *qty* to show in the browser

After selecting color, size and entering a quite big number on `qty` box, I can see an alert showing the wanted *available qty*.
See for example the image below, where it says that only 109 (highlighted in red) can be purchased.
[image: browser screenshot of wanted qty]

The alert message translates to English like:

> You can buy **x qty** only

I want to scrape the "x qty" from the alert message.

#### Tried with Selenium

I can get the alert text including available *qty* by below code using Selenium.

```py
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="detail"]/form/div/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/ul/li[1]/a""").click()    
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="detail"]/form/div/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/ul/li[1]/a""").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="detail_multi_option"]/li/div[1]/input""")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="detail_multi_option"]/li/div[1]/input""").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="detail_multi_option"]/li/div[1]/input""").send_keys(1000)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="detail_multi_option"]/li/div[1]/input""").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    
time.sleep(5)
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
print(alert.text)
```

#### My Problem

Although I can scrape that *qty* number, I couldn't find the corresponding tag in the page's HTML (using Inspect Element).

As I don't want to use Selenium, how can I get the available *qty* using *requests* library?

Comment: Post a [mcve] so we can help you out. This includes version numbers of software/libs. End of Review.

Comment: "Help me figure out how the HTML code of this website works" is not on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've changed question. Can you help?